# C# MVC - How can I pass some method arguments as parameters inside a Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(string par)
{
    Model myMod = new Model();
    myMod.Attribute = par;
    return View(myMod);
}
```

In the Test View I'd like to retrieve and print that attribute...
like this:

```
@model Project.Models.Model

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute)
```

But by doing in that way I'm not able to retrieve the data from the action.

Comment: Using Model as the name of your ViewModel class is not a good choice. In Razor... @Model refers to the model passed to the view. It will became hard to understate... not sure it the intellisense will work as intended also.

Comment: View logic looks OK. Are you sure that `par` is set when you call the action?

Comment: I tried to write the url manually, i.e. `localhost:8090/Home/Test/thisisthevalue` and I suppose it opens a page, since the View is ok, with "_thisisthevalue_" displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, the property is called, `Attribute`, but in the view, you are referencing `Attrubute`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute)
```